# android: visual/art assets

Tags: android, image, assets

I am trying to make a game for the android. I currently have all of my art assets loaded into the drawables folder, but my question is how do I actually reference a specific one to render it?

I know that the files each have a unique @id, and I probably have to implement in the @override of the onDraw(canvas) method. so the question is how do I actually display the image to the screen?

I have looked through a good half dozen books and all those talk about is getting an image off the web, or manually drawing it with the paint functionality, but I have the assets ready to go in .bmp, and they are complex enough that coding paint to draw them by hand will be a very great migrain.

I would prefer a direction to look in (specific book, tutorial, blog, open source code[assuming quality comments])I am still kinda learning java as my 2nd programming language and so I am not to the point of translating pseudocode directly to java yet.

[added in edit]
does drawing using Paint() every frame have a lower overhead then rendering a bitmap, and only changing the display when it changes?

Answer (score 1):

for 2Dgames I would recommend you to use [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)

load your image as a bitmap and let the canvas draw that bitmap.

to animate the images there are two possible way :

- You could inflate the view
- Create a looping thread to call the draw function

[Here's some good starting tutorial about displaying image in Android, especially for games](http://obviam.net/index.php/displaying-graphics-with-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the drawBitmap variants of the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class. A canvas object is passed in the onDraw method. You can use the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) class to load a resourse.

You can read a nice tutorial [here](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html).